# how to configuration Mock Test with DAO layer Spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc

i working with Spring mvc, using hibernate and JPA configuration,relation      many-to-many, i'm using view technologies(jsp) test method in DAO(with     controller,service) ok, when i move to writing test for DAO class , it fail, i    don't know, Where am I wrong?, please could you tell me ? thanks you !
Student.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student {
@Id
@Column(name = "studentNumber", nullable = false)
private Integer studentNumber;
@Column(name = "studentName", nullable = false)
private String studentName;
@Column(name = "birthDay", nullable = false)
private String birthDay;
@Column(name = "birthPlace", nullable = false)
private String birthPlace;
@Column(name = "admissionDay", nullable = false)
private String admissionDay;
@Column(name = "score", nullable = false)
private Float score;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy =      "studentNumbers")
private Set<ClassRoom> classRooms = new HashSet<ClassRoom>();
```

ClassRoom.java

> ```
> @Entity
>  @Table(name = "ClassRoom")
>  public class ClassRoom {
> @Id
> @Column(name = "classRoomID", unique = true, nullable = false)
> private String classRoomID;
> @Column(name = "classRoomName", nullable = false)
> private String classRoomName;
> @Column(name = "teacherName", nullable = false)
> private String teacherName;
> @JoinTable(name = "ClassRoom_Student", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "classRoomID", referencedColumnName = "classRoomID", nullable = false, updatable = false) , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "studentNumber", referencedColumnName = "studentNumber", nullable = false, updatable = false) )
> @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
> private Set<Student> studentNumbers = new HashSet<Student>();
> ```

DAO class

> ```
> @Repository
> public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO {
> @PersistenceContext(unitName = "default")
> private EntityManager entityManager;
> @Override
> public boolean insert(Student student) {
>     entityManager.persist(student);
>     return true;
> }
> @Override
> public boolean update(Student student) {
>     entityManager.merge(student);
>     return true;
> }
> @Override
> public boolean delete(Integer studentNumber) {
>      Student student = entityManager.find(Student.class, studentNumber);
>      entityManager.remove(student);
>     return true;
> }
> @Override
> public Student getStudentByStudentNumber(Integer studentNumber) {
>     Student student = entityManager.find(Student.class, studentNumber);
>     return student;
> }
> @Override
> public List<Student> getAllStudent() {
>     return entityManager.createQuery("FROM Student").getResultList();
> }
> @Override
> public List<String> getClassOfStudent(Integer studentNumber) {
>     return entityManager
>             .createQuery("SELECT cs.classRoomID FROM Class_Student cs WHERE cs.studentNumber=" + studentNumber)
>             .getResultList();
> }
> @Override
> public boolean deleteStudentClassStudent(Integer studentNumber) {
>     Query query = entityManager
>             .createQuery("DELETE FROM ClassRoom_Student cs WHERE cs.studentNumber = " + studentNumber);
>     query.executeUpdate();
>     return true;
> }}
> ```

and mockTest

> ```
> @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:applicationContext.xml" })
>   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
>  public class Mockito {
>  @Mock
>  private static Student studentMock;
>  @Mock
> private static ClassRoom classMock;
> @Autowired
> private StudentDAO studentDAO;
> @Autowired
> private ClassRoomDAO classRoomDAO;
> @Test
> public void testCreateObject() {
>     assertNotNull(studentDAO);
>     assertNotNull(classRoomDAO);
> }
> @Test
> public void insertTest() {
>     Student student = new Student(111006, "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", 10f);
>     studentDAO.insert(student);
>     List<Student> listStudent = studentDAO.getAllStudent();
>     when(studentDAO.insert(student)).thenReturn(true);
>     assertTrue(0 == listStudent.size());
> }
> @Test
> public void testgetStudentByStudentNumber() {
>     Student student = new Student();
>   when(studentDAO.getStudentByStudentNumber(111000002)).thenReturn(student);
>     assertTrue(student != null);
> }
> @Test
> public void updateTest() {
>     Student student = studentDAO.getStudentByStudentNumber(111002);
>     student.setStudentName("new name");
>     student.setAdmissionDay("new Day");
>     student.setBirthDay("new Day");
>     student.setBirthPlace("new Day");
>     student.setScore(8f);
>     when(studentDAO.update(student)).thenReturn(false);
>     assertTrue(student == null);
> }
> @Test
> public void deleteTest() {
>     when(studentDAO.delete(111005)).thenReturn(true);
>     Student stu = studentDAO.getStudentByStudentNumber(111005);
>     assertTrue(stu != null);
> }
> @Test
> public void getAllStudentTest() {
>     List<Student> studentS = studentDAO.getAllStudent();
>     assertTrue(studentS.size() != 0);
> }
> @Test
> public void getStudentByIdTest() {
> }
> ```
>
> }

where the error occurs

> ```
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ids.demo.dao.StudentDAO com.ids.demo.test.Mockito.studentDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ids.demo.dao.StudentDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
> ... 26 more
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ids.demo.dao.StudentDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
> ... 28 more
> ```

Comment: your @Repository StudentDao is not in application context, check the scan of context in your xml file, and check if persistentUnit name is correct